# How can I check if numbers of the table column are grather than X?

Tags: cypress

I need validating if values of the table column are greater Than 0.01 and least than 99999999.99

The table have 230 rows

I have already did this:

`cy.get('#credits [align="right"]') .invoke('text') .then(parseFloat) .should('be.gte', 0.01)`

but in the results appear this message:
expected 'Infinity' to be at least 0.01

should I do a for?

Comment: What are you testing?

Answer (score 3):

Likely the result `infinity` is because `parseInt` sees all rows texts at once and cannot properly parse one big string of all values.

Try with `.each()`, at least it's the first step you will take:

```js
cy.get('#credits [align="right"]')
  .each($el => {
    cy.wrap($el)
      .invoke('text')
      .then(parseFloat)
      .should('be.gte', 0.01)
  })
```